# Installing plugin to application running on Linux SUSE

Tags: linux

I have an application running on a SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11. A plugin is available which is installed by running an installation program (which unpacks, creates directories and registry entries etc. etc.).

The version of the plugin and the version of the application running on the server must be the same. The version of the plugin at my disposal is not the same as the version of the application running on the server.

The problem is that the installation program checks the version of the plugin.

Does anybody have an idea what I could do? Ideally I would be able to alter the installation program so that it does not perform the check, but I have no idea how to or if it is even possible.

Please note: I have NO idea about Linux.

Comment: There's probably a good reason why the versions are required to be the same.

Comment: What you could do is use [Google](http://google.com), or maybe even the web site of the vendor who wrote the plugin, to help you find the correct version of the plugin for the version of the application you have...

Comment: Of course using the same version would be preferable, but I know that technically it is possible to use different versions. The problem I have is that I cannot get hold of the proper plugin version nor change the version of the application to match the plugin. Hence, I am looking for a work-around.